# Passing list of int to Web API from RestSharp Client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

When I use code below from REST Sharp I am not able to pass `listOfSelectedTicketsIds` it always null.

**Request of Rest Sharp .net Client**

```
 var _stDeveloperApi = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1/");
            var url = string.Format("api/v1/SignalR/MultiClickMode");
            var listOfSelectedTicketsIds = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
            var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
            request.AddParameter("listOfSelectedTicketsIds", listOfSelectedTicketsIds, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            var response = _stDeveloperApi.Execute(request);
```

**Web API Method**

```
[HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage MultiClickMode(List<int> listOfSelectedTicketsIds)
        { 
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your client code like this.

```
var _stDeveloperApi = new RestClient("http://127.0.0.1/");
var url = string.Format("api/v1/SignalR/MultiClickMode");
var listOfSelectedTicketsIds = new List<int> { 2, 3 };
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET);
listOfSelectedTicketsIds.ForEach(t => 
            request.AddParameter(
                "listOfSelectedTicketsIds", t, ParameterType.GetOrPost));
var response = _stDeveloperApi.Execute(request);
```

Change the web API action method signature like this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage MultiClickMode(
                               [FromUri]List<int> listOfSelectedTicketsIds)
```